# having both gCal and individual built-in events in fullCalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

i would like to have my own events displaying on the calendar - along side an imported gCal link with additional events.

is this possible? what would the syntax look like?

Thanks!

Comment: Check eventSources in Fullcalendar. I can give you a few pointers like:

[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537009/how-do-i-populate-the-fullcalendar-using-my-database-values/19560652#19560652

Comment: Thanks - i know that well - my question is about combining the 2 formats- thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use multiple event sources like in the question Henrique recommended

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    eventSources: [
        '/gCalFeed',
        '/feed2'
    ]
});
```

*gCalFeed* would be the URL from the gCAL feed and *feed2* a feed you created that delivers your events, for instance as a [JSON](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/), to full calendar

Comment: thanks. not what i had intended, but i guess this should work, thanks